# Read a txt file using space delimiter

Tags: import

I have a txt file "data.txt". This contain data like

```
a   1
b   2
c   3
```

I want to import this file into two list like $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{1,2,3\}$.I have tried using SplitBy, but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list=Import["finename.txt", "Table"]
```

should do the trick. With the following you should be able to assign values, i.e get a list of explicit assigned values

```
MapIndexed[(x[#2[[1]]] = #1[[2]]) &, list];
```

You can use

```
?x
```

to check that.

**Edit**

If you want an array I think the following should do the trick:

```
x=list[[All, 2]];
```

Comment: Ahhh, this is better. I don't have to convert from string to expression.

Comment: @sslucifer glad I was able to help. Maybe you should check the edit in case you want an array. That should also work I think.

Comment: Transpose[list] should also work, right?

Comment: @sslucifer yes, it should also do the trick. you're right :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
d3 = ReadList["C:/data.txt", Record, RecordSeparators -> {"\n"}, 
  WordSeparators -> {"\t", " "}]
```

> {"a   1", "b   2", "c   3"}

Now you can convert this list of strings to expressions and execute `Transpose` (assuming that's what you want);

```
Transpose@ToExpression@(StringSplit /@ d3)
```

> {{a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}}

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what representations you eventually want, but if you import it as a string...

```
data = Import[pathtofile]
```

...then you can start with StringSplit...

```
list = StringSplit[data]
```

...from there you can partition and reorganize...

```
Transpose[Partition[list, 2]]
```

Now, the individual elements are still strings, but I don't know what you want them to be. You may need to apply more transformations or you may want to use import options.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I wanted all the numbers in float, so I used ToExpression to convert all the strings to numbers.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility :

```
data =
  "a 1
b 2
c 3";

file = Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "test.txt"}], data]

ReadList[file, Word, RecordLists -> True]
```

> {{"a", "1"}, {"b", "2"}, {"c", "3"}}

Then use Transpose